# How to count only integers in a string

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I have this small piece of code that I'm trying to work on that takes in a string, and adds one to a counter for every number in the string separated by a space.  However, if it runs into something that is not an integer, it immediately stops the counter which isn't what I want it to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int counter;

int main()
{           
cout << "Please input string: ";
string input;
getline(cin, input);
istringstream ss(input);

    int num;
    while(ss >> num)
    {
        counter++;
    }

    cout << "Amount of integers in string: " << counter << endl;

}
```

For example, if I input the string `3 4 5`, it will correctly return 3 integers in the string, but if I input something like `3 4 x 6 t 8`,  it will say I only had two integers in the string.

How do I fix this?

Comment: So "3 4 5" should result in a count of 3, what about "3 4 5 123", should it result in a count of 6 or 4?

Comment: You want to know the number of digits in the string that are not preceded by a digit. So just go through all the characters in the string and increment a counter every time you encounter a digit not preceded by a digit.

Comment: Your test `while(ss >> num)` fails on the first non-integer and the loop exits. You need to clear the fail state and then consume the input (probably one character at a time) and try to read the integral again.

Comment: Oops, sorry I didn't specify! "3 4 5 123" would result in a count of 4.

Comment: A much more natural approach would be to use regular expressions.

`([0-9]+ )` is your pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ss >> num` will put the stream in an error state as soon as it encounters a non-integer, which will make `while (ss >> num)` terminate.

Like many other problems, this can be solved by introducing a level of indirection of some sort.
In this case, you can use indirection through a second stream:

```
istringstream ss(input);
string word;
while (ss >> word)
{
    istringstream maybenumber(word);
    int number = 0;
    if (maybenumber >> number)
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not unelegant but quite a bit of overhead.

Comment: @PeterSchneider What is the root of all evil?

Comment: Premature overhead. (My 4 core 3 GHz boots slower than my 1 core 8MHz 1985.)

Answer (score 2):

The `operator>>` returns the stream which has a conversion to bool indicating whether any error flags are set; that's what is used in your while loop. If the character sequence at the read position in the stream is not an int, the fail bit is set and the stream converts to `false` in the loop, ending the program.

You probably want to check that bit in the loop. If it is the fail bit (and not eof), clear it, read away the string that's between the ints, and continue in the loop.

You were not very exact with your specification; the algorithm described above would return 1 for the string "123 abx2". If you want to return 2 or 4 here you must inspect the data at the single character level.

Answer (score 1):

Use [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/):

```
std::string str = "4 a h a 1 23";
size_t countNumbers(0);
for ( size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i++ )
{ 
  if( isdigit(str[i]) && ( i == 0 || isspace(str[i-1]) ) )  
  { countNumbers++; }
}
std::cout << "There are " << countNumbers << " numbers" << 
             " in the string \"" << str << "\"." << std::endl;
```

Comment: I can imagine that the numbers can have more than 1 digit but should increase the counter only by one, e.g. "a 123 b" should return 1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **check if the read input value is a digit followed by empty space or an alphabetic letter first** and then increment the counter. A possible implementation looks like this

```
int main()
{           
    cout << "Please input string: ";
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);

    int counter = 0;
    if(input.size() == 1 && isdigit(input[0])){
        counter ++;
    }else{
        for(int i = 1; i < input.size(); ++i){
            // works for all but the last element
           if(isdigit(input[i-1]) && (isspace(input[i]) || isalpha(input[i]))) counter++;
        }
        // check the last element
        if(isdigit(input[input.size()-1])) counter ++;
    }

    cout << "Amount of integers in string: " << counter << endl;
}
```

### Note:

The above code considers even a string where the integer is among non-integer characters, e.g.:`5dkjfkd`

Comment: Won't that count the digits, as opposed to the integers?

Comment: @juanchopanza that is a valid point. For example, the integer 123 will be counter as 3 digits.

Comment: @juanchopanza really ugly, but it works. Do you Like it?

Answer (score 0):

In the while condition you should check for the end of the string, not for a number.
Then, check if it is a number to increase your counter.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` condition evaluates to false whenever a non-integer is encountered. To correct this, loop until the end of the string, and only increase counter if you encounter an integer.

Somewhat like,

```
bool checknum (string x)
{
    for (auto &i: x) if (!isdigit(i)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

```
string num;
while (!ss.eof())
{
    getline (ss, num, ' ');
    if (checknum(num)) counter++;
}
```